# Git apply binary file diff. "patch does not apply" error

Tags: bash, git, github, binary, diff

I modified a binary file in test_branch, then, in another branch did:

```
git diff --full-index --binary test_branch binary_file_name.dat | git apply
```

However, I get the following error:

```
error: the patch applies to 'binary_file_name.dat' (e4d7fc486a4ddd1638445449c5bfcec760b23c7f), which does not match the current contents.
error: binary_file_name.dat: patch does not apply
```

Does anyone know how I can fix the error and apply the binary diff?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git diff --full-index --binary test_branch binary_file_name.dat` is equivalent to `git diff --full-index --binary test_branch HEAD binary_file_name.dat`. The diff means the change that updates `binary_file_name.dat` of `test_branch` to the `binary_file_name.dat` of the other branch (`HEAD`). But you are now on the other branch, which means the current `binary_file_name.dat` is already the updated version. So swap `HEAD` and `test_branch` in `git diff` and it will work as expected.

```
git diff --full-index --binary HEAD test_branch binary_file_name.dat | git apply
```